# php | Simple question on conditional statement

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I'm new to php and I would like to have a conditional statement like this:

```
if ($foo != 'Any') { $condition .= '$this_foo == $foo &&';}
if ($bar != 'Any') { $condition .= '$this_bar == $bar &&';}
if ($txt != 'Any') { $condition .= '$this_txt == $txt &&';}
$condition .= '$num1 > 0 && $num2 < 1000';

if (...[php would parse the $condition variable])
{
  someoperations
}
```

What is the proper syntax for the if statement to parse the variable $condition? So the conditional statement depends on the other variables and to prevent a long nested conditional statement.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's not exactly parsing, but you could evaluate your condition as the code is executed.

```
$condition = true;
if ($foo != 'Any') { $condition = $condition && ($this_foo == $foo);}
if ($bar != 'Any') { $condition = $condition && ($this_bar == $bar);}
if ($txt != 'Any') { $condition = $condition && ($this_txt == $txt);}
$condition = $condition && ($num1 > 0 && $num2 < 1000);

if ($condition)
{
  someoperations
}
```

So let's say that `$foo != 'Any'` is `true`, that would result in

```
$condition = true && ($this_foo == $foo) && ($num1 > 0 && $num2 < 1000);
```

Let's pretend `$this_foo == $foo`, `$num1 == 45` and `$num2 == 2300`

```
$condition = true && true && (true && false);
$condition = false;
```

and your if won't execute.

Comment: thanks for this! it helped me. I'll upvote this when I have the reputation.

Comment: there we go. I only joined here yesterday so I'm a newbie. =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is

```
if (eval("return " . $condition)) {...}
```

Making sure to check for the FALSE case if the parsing fails.